# Wrong output in my php code in EditRocket

Tags: php, html

I created `hello.php` file in `EditRocket` on my Mac and wrote this simple code

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello world!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

but i got wrong output

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world!</body>
</html>
```

The correct output is just `Hello world!` only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Output is ok, did you get it in the browser or in the php interpreter?

Comment: @Toumash no , in php interpreter

Comment: See my answer. Should be satisfying : ) If so - please accept it as an solution (It keeps StackOverflo clean and users happy) - i see that you didn't on your previous question from May

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is - interpreter dumps whole output from the script by design.
Output is `Hello world!` but **ONLY** [for internet browsers, html renderers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

> Web browsers can read HTML files and render them into visible or
>   audible web pages. Browsers do not display the HTML tags and scripts,
>   but use them to interpret the content of the page.

They are parsing html and gives you graphical representation.

If you want to only print `Hello world!` as a whole output just remove html tags from the code so it will consist only of:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world!";
?>
```